# Meteor - Why 2 users are created?

Tags: meteor

Trying to create and auth anonymous do:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {

  // Allocate a new user id.
  if (!Meteor.userId()) {
    var pass = Random.create().id();
    var email = pass+'@example.com';
    Accounts.createUser({password: pass, email: email}, function(err){
      Meteor.loginWithPassword({password: pass, email: email});
    });
  } else {
  }
});
```

This almost works well. But sometimes meteor creates two users at once. :(

Comment: adding `&& !Meteor.loggingIn()` do nothing. that may create two users in users table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by, "meteor creates two users at once"...

If you mean, "why do user records keep being created when I visit the site" then its because Meteor takes a bit of time to log in the user and until that process is complete, Meteor.userId() will be null. See http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_loggingin

If the code you posted is actually creating 2 users the first time its visited (with a clean db) then I'm surprised as well.  A full repro would help debug that case; perhaps you can update your answer with a link to github?